# Ejabberd mobile connectivity, lost or delayed messages

Tags: mobile, connection, xmpp, ejabberd

I have an instant messaging website that could be used with desktop or mobile. I realize some messages are not delivered or delayed while using mobile browsers.

### Situation

I am using Ejabberd 17.04, with Stream Management, Offline Message enabled, connecting with Strophe on the client side (with XEP-0184 Message Delivery Receipts).

Here are some of the configurations:

- mod_stream_mgmt

  ```
  resume_timeout: 300
  max_resume_timeout: 300
  resend_on_timeout: true
  ```
- mod_offline

  ```
  access_max_user_messages: (100 for normal user)
  store_empty_body: unless_chat_state
  ```

---

### Questions:

1. As `max_resume_timeout` is set to 300s, how would the message be handled between the 300s while the client is not responding? Will the message be resent when the client **resume (within the 300s)** the stream?
2. I understand that any message(s) that was not sent to the user within the 300s would be re-sent and should be handled by offline message if the user is not reconnected at that time. However, some of the offline messages are not being sent **immediately** after reconnect. How could I minimize the delay?
3. Should I use `MAM (XEP-0313)` to fetch all the message between the disconnect and reconnect of the user to avoid message loss?
4. Are there any things I could do to avoid or minimize the UNSTABLE connection to the server?